# Place Labels on the Grid

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, data-driven-pages, grids-graticules, arcgis-10.4

I am stuck with placing Label on the Grid lines. Below is the data grid on the map. I created the grid using data driven pages.
After I turned on the Label, the labelling appeared inside the grid. I want it to be placed on the line itself with a little buffer around it. I have explored the placement properties of the grid layer and it looks as if there is no option there[image: Current Grid]

I wish I could placed the Labeling on the gridLines/borders instead of inside the grid.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the labes manually. Try to right click on the layer in the Table of view and Convert labels to annotation. Then click three times on the one label (in Layout view) to select it and then hold CTRL and drag to select all. Then you move all labels the same way. It's maybe the easiest way for you.

Or 2nd option you can set Offset X and Offset Y. You can find it at Layer properties > Labels > Label Styles... > Properties > Symbol Properties > Edit Symbol. There you have Offset X and Offset Y settings. It's kind of long way there :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a [Reference Grid](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/a-quick-tour-of-the-grids-and-graticules-wizard.htm) from the Grids tab of your Data Frame Properties.

[image]

You will just need to take care to line it up with the vector grid that you generated.